# Routing between bridge network and host interface?

Tags: networking, routing, iptables, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to set up a docker host server in my network (Ubuntu 18.04), and I'm struggling with wiring up the network.

Ideally, I'd like to set it up such that I can route traffic to a specific IP address on the host's physical network to a docker network.

So, if my host's IP address is 192.168.0.10, then I could route traffic from say, 192.168.0.11 to a docker network

```
192.168.0.10 --> [host]
192.168.0.11 --> [172.18.0.0/24]
```

From the outside, the entire docker network would look like one address. Just not sure how to set up the NATing rules for that setup.

I've tried adding a bridge to the netplan config, but that took down network access to the entire host:

```
bridges:
  web_bridge:
    addresses: [ 192.168.0.11/24 ]
    gateway4: 192.168.0.1
    nameservers:
        search: [ ... ]
        addresses:
          - "8.8.8.8"
    interfaces:
      - ens160
    parameters:
      stp: false
      forward-delay: 2
      hello-time: 2
      max-age: 12
```

---

So, how can I set up communication such that traffic to a specific IP address on the eth0 interface is routed - with NATing - to a bridge network?

I think I can accomplish it with iptable masquerade rules, but I'm not sure how to use that to assign a new ip address

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this myself;

First I created the new docker network:

```
docker network create \
  --driver=bridge \
  --subnet=172.21.0.0/24 \
  --gateway=172.21.0.1 \
  web_bridge
```

Next, I added 0.11 and 0.12 as aliases to the interface at eth0

Then rules to route traffic destined to 0.11 to that docker network, and opne port 80:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.11 -j DNAT --to-destination 
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -d 192.168.0.11 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 172.21.0.2:80
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.21.0.2 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 172.21.0.1
```

And finally, I used expose (not ports) in the docker container config, to bind to `"192.178.0.11:80:80"`

This allows each docker-compose stack to have an isolated network, with visibility on the host's physical network.